# Delphi IDE - Enable highlighting of selected variable (like Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, syntax-highlighting

In Visual Studio when I highlight a function or variable all other instances of it also get highlighted. I find this to be very useful. Does anyone know if Delphi can do this somehow? When using the search in Delphi it highlights all found instances, so sometimes I quickly copy and search but this is a lot slower than just clicking the text.

Visual Studio highlighting:

[image]

Comment: Install CnPack ...

Comment: Once you've installed CnPack, you'll find the setting in *IDE Enhancement Settings->Source Highlight Settings->Code Structure Highlights->Enable Background Highlight Current Identifier at Cursor.*

Comment: thanks to both of you! feel free to make it an answer if you want

Comment: Incremental search does it. Press ctrl+e, then type 'thisisvar'. Cumbersome though....

Comment: Also, Sync Edit feature can do that in cumbersome way.

Comment: CnPack is an awesome tool, though it has so many features that it takes  time to figure out what features to enable/disable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Delphi 11.3 and later then this feature is enabled and built-in by default as can be seen by the bottom screenshots:

[image: Delphi IDE code highlighting]

[image: Delphi IDE code highlighting]

[image: Delphi IDE code highlighting]

With older versions of Delphi, you can install [CnPack](https://github.com/cnpack/cnwizards) and as @Ken stated in the comments, you can enable it as so: "You'll find the setting in IDE Enhancement Settings->Source Highlight Settings->Code Structure Highlights->Enable Background Highlight Current Identifier at Cursor."